# Starter Question, overlay Div with Text over an Animation

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to overlay a `div` over another `div`.
But there are some problems because i am newbie.

```js
// particle.min.js hosted on GitHub
// Scroll down for initialisation code

!function(a){var b="object"==typeof self&&self.self===self&&self||"object"==typeof global&&global.global===global&&global;"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define(["exports"],function(c){b.ParticleNetwork=a(b,c)}):"object"==typeof module&&module.exports?module.exports=a(b,{}):b.ParticleNetwork=a(b,{})}(function(a,b){var c=function(a){this.canvas=a.canvas,this.g=a.g,this.particleColor=a.options.particleColor,this.x=Math.random()*this.canvas.width,this.y=Math.random()*this.canvas.height,this.velocity={x:(Math.random()-.5)*a.options.velocity,y:(Math.random()-.5)*a.options.velocity}};return c.prototype.update=function(){(this.x>this.canvas.width+20||this.x<-20)&&(this.velocity.x=-this.velocity.x),(this.y>this.canvas.height+20||this.y<-20)&&(this.velocity.y=-this.velocity.y),this.x+=this.velocity.x,this.y+=this.velocity.y},c.prototype.h=function(){this.g.beginPath(),this.g.fillStyle=this.particleColor,this.g.globalAlpha=.7,this.g.arc(this.x,this.y,1.5,0,2*Math.PI),this.g.fill()},b=function(a,b){this.i=a,this.i.size={width:this.i.offsetWidth,height:this.i.offsetHeight},b=void 0!==b?b:{},this.options={particleColor:void 0!==b.particleColor?b.particleColor:"#fff",background:void 0!==b.background?b.background:"#1a252f",interactive:void 0!==b.interactive?b.interactive:!0,velocity:this.setVelocity(b.speed),density:this.j(b.density)},this.init()},b.prototype.init=function(){if(this.k=document.createElement("div"),this.i.appendChild(this.k),this.l(this.k,{position:"absolute",top:0,left:0,bottom:0,right:0,"z-index":1}),/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.background))this.l(this.k,{background:this.options.background});else{if(!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i.test(this.options.background))return console.error("Please specify a valid background image or hexadecimal color"),!1;this.l(this.k,{background:'url("'+this.options.background+'") no-repeat center',"background-size":"cover"})}if(!/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.particleColor))return console.error("Please specify a valid particleColor hexadecimal color"),!1;this.canvas=document.createElement("canvas"),this.i.appendChild(this.canvas),this.g=this.canvas.getContext("2d"),this.canvas.width=this.i.size.width,this.canvas.height=this.i.size.height,this.l(this.i,{position:"relative"}),this.l(this.canvas,{"z-index":"20",position:"relative"}),window.addEventListener("resize",function(){return this.i.offsetWidth===this.i.size.width&&this.i.offsetHeight===this.i.size.height?!1:(this.canvas.width=this.i.size.width=this.i.offsetWidth,this.canvas.height=this.i.size.height=this.i.offsetHeight,clearTimeout(this.m),void(this.m=setTimeout(function(){this.o=[];for(var a=0;a<this.canvas.width*this.canvas.height/this.options.density;a++)this.o.push(new c(this));this.options.interactive&&this.o.push(this.p),requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))}.bind(this),500)))}.bind(this)),this.o=[];for(var a=0;a<this.canvas.width*this.canvas.height/this.options.density;a++)this.o.push(new c(this));this.options.interactive&&(this.p=new c(this),this.p.velocity={x:0,y:0},this.o.push(this.p),this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove",function(a){this.p.x=a.clientX-this.canvas.offsetLeft,this.p.y=a.clientY-this.canvas.offsetTop}.bind(this)),this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup",function(a){this.p.velocity={x:(Math.random()-.5)*this.options.velocity,y:(Math.random()-.5)*this.options.velocity},this.p=new c(this),this.p.velocity={x:0,y:0},this.o.push(this.p)}.bind(this))),requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))},b.prototype.update=function(){this.g.clearRect(0,0,this.canvas.width,this.canvas.height),this.g.globalAlpha=1;for(var a=0;a<this.o.length;a++){this.o[a].update(),this.o[a].h();for(var b=this.o.length-1;b>a;b--){var c=Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.o[a].x-this.o[b].x,2)+Math.pow(this.o[a].y-this.o[b].y,2));c>120||(this.g.beginPath(),this.g.strokeStyle=this.options.particleColor,this.g.globalAlpha=(120-c)/120,this.g.lineWidth=.7,this.g.moveTo(this.o[a].x,this.o[a].y),this.g.lineTo(this.o[b].x,this.o[b].y),this.g.stroke())}}0!==this.options.velocity&&requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))},b.prototype.setVelocity=function(a){return"fast"===a?1:"slow"===a?.33:"none"===a?0:.66},b.prototype.j=function(a){return"high"===a?5e3:"low"===a?2e4:isNaN(parseInt(a,10))?1e4:a},b.prototype.l=function(a,b){for(var c in b)a.style[c]=b[c]},b});

// Initialisation

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
var options = {
  particleColor: '#888',
  background: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/master/img/demo-bg.jpg',
  interactive: true,
  speed: 'medium',
  density: 'high'
};
var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#particle-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: inherit;
    float: none;
}
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#back,
.overstyle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 50%;
}
.overstyle h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 230%;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
}
.overstyle {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
        <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
            <div id="particle-canvas" id="back"></div>
            <script src='https://rawgit.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/master/particle-network.min.js'></script>
            <script  src="js/index.js"></script>
            <!--- Content Div --->
            <div style="width: 100%; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);" class="overstyle">
                <h1>TestFont</h1>
            </div>
            <!--- End of Content Div --->
        </div>
    </body>
```

The code is a `div` with `id="particle-canavas"`. For more information about that visit this page [here](https://codepen.io/JulianLaval/pen/KpLXOO/).

This is my Css [stylesheet](https://pastebin.com/Mv3yQ0rx).
So now how could I improve the overlay `div` with class "overstyle"?

Thanks for all help.

Comment: So you want `.overstyle` above the other elements, is that right? Have you just tried `position: absolute`? That should do the trick.

Comment: correct. But absolute doesnt work. Have a look in my stylesheet

Comment: could you just provide a fiddle? that would help a lot.

Comment: make use of the Z-index css property

Comment: Thanks to all answers. I tried the code of Jaclyn Ciringione but the best thing would be to set all things in the div to align center. Is this possible? I tried text-align: center; in css at .overstyle h1 { }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This centers as you need. 
When I need to center something, I always try:

```
width:100%;
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
```

```js
// particle.min.js hosted on GitHub
// Scroll down for initialisation code

! function(a) {
  var b = "object" == typeof self && self.self === self && self || "object" == typeof global && global.global === global && global;
  "function" == typeof define && define.amd ? define(["exports"], function(c) {
    b.ParticleNetwork = a(b, c)
  }) : "object" == typeof module && module.exports ? module.exports = a(b, {}) : b.ParticleNetwork = a(b, {})
}(function(a, b) {
  var c = function(a) {
    this.canvas = a.canvas, this.g = a.g, this.particleColor = a.options.particleColor, this.x = Math.random() * this.canvas.width, this.y = Math.random() * this.canvas.height, this.velocity = {
      x: (Math.random() - .5) * a.options.velocity,
      y: (Math.random() - .5) * a.options.velocity
    }
  };
  return c.prototype.update = function() {
    (this.x > this.canvas.width + 20 || this.x < -20) && (this.velocity.x = -this.velocity.x), (this.y > this.canvas.height + 20 || this.y < -20) && (this.velocity.y = -this.velocity.y), this.x += this.velocity.x, this.y += this.velocity.y
  }, c.prototype.h = function() {
    this.g.beginPath(), this.g.fillStyle = this.particleColor, this.g.globalAlpha = .7, this.g.arc(this.x, this.y, 1.5, 0, 2 * Math.PI), this.g.fill()
  }, b = function(a, b) {
    this.i = a, this.i.size = {
      width: this.i.offsetWidth,
      height: this.i.offsetHeight
    }, b = void 0 !== b ? b : {}, this.options = {
      particleColor: void 0 !== b.particleColor ? b.particleColor : "#fff",
      background: void 0 !== b.background ? b.background : "#1a252f",
      interactive: void 0 !== b.interactive ? b.interactive : !0,
      velocity: this.setVelocity(b.speed),
      density: this.j(b.density)
    }, this.init()
  }, b.prototype.init = function() {
    if (this.k = document.createElement("div"), this.i.appendChild(this.k), this.l(this.k, {
        position: "absolute",
        top: 0,
        left: 0,
        bottom: 0,
        right: 0,
        "z-index": 1
      }), /(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.background)) this.l(this.k, {
      background: this.options.background
    });
    else {
      if (!/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|tiff|png)$/i.test(this.options.background)) return console.error("Please specify a valid background image or hexadecimal color"), !1;
      this.l(this.k, {
        background: 'url("' + this.options.background + '") no-repeat center',
        "background-size": "cover"
      })
    }
    if (!/(^#[0-9A-F]{6}$)|(^#[0-9A-F]{3}$)/i.test(this.options.particleColor)) return console.error("Please specify a valid particleColor hexadecimal color"), !1;
    this.canvas = document.createElement("canvas"), this.i.appendChild(this.canvas), this.g = this.canvas.getContext("2d"), this.canvas.width = this.i.size.width, this.canvas.height = this.i.size.height, this.l(this.i, {
      position: "relative"
    }), this.l(this.canvas, {
      "z-index": "20",
      position: "relative"
    }), window.addEventListener("resize", function() {
      return this.i.offsetWidth === this.i.size.width && this.i.offsetHeight === this.i.size.height ? !1 : (this.canvas.width = this.i.size.width = this.i.offsetWidth, this.canvas.height = this.i.size.height = this.i.offsetHeight, clearTimeout(this.m), void(this.m = setTimeout(function() {
        this.o = [];
        for (var a = 0; a < this.canvas.width * this.canvas.height / this.options.density; a++) this.o.push(new c(this));
        this.options.interactive && this.o.push(this.p), requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))
      }.bind(this), 500)))
    }.bind(this)), this.o = [];
    for (var a = 0; a < this.canvas.width * this.canvas.height / this.options.density; a++) this.o.push(new c(this));
    this.options.interactive && (this.p = new c(this), this.p.velocity = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    }, this.o.push(this.p), this.canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function(a) {
      this.p.x = a.clientX - this.canvas.offsetLeft, this.p.y = a.clientY - this.canvas.offsetTop
    }.bind(this)), this.canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function(a) {
      this.p.velocity = {
        x: (Math.random() - .5) * this.options.velocity,
        y: (Math.random() - .5) * this.options.velocity
      }, this.p = new c(this), this.p.velocity = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0
      }, this.o.push(this.p)
    }.bind(this))), requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))
  }, b.prototype.update = function() {
    this.g.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height), this.g.globalAlpha = 1;
    for (var a = 0; a < this.o.length; a++) {
      this.o[a].update(), this.o[a].h();
      for (var b = this.o.length - 1; b > a; b--) {
        var c = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(this.o[a].x - this.o[b].x, 2) + Math.pow(this.o[a].y - this.o[b].y, 2));
        c > 120 || (this.g.beginPath(), this.g.strokeStyle = this.options.particleColor, this.g.globalAlpha = (120 - c) / 120, this.g.lineWidth = .7, this.g.moveTo(this.o[a].x, this.o[a].y), this.g.lineTo(this.o[b].x, this.o[b].y), this.g.stroke())
      }
    }
    0 !== this.options.velocity && requestAnimationFrame(this.update.bind(this))
  }, b.prototype.setVelocity = function(a) {
    return "fast" === a ? 1 : "slow" === a ? .33 : "none" === a ? 0 : .66
  }, b.prototype.j = function(a) {
    return "high" === a ? 5e3 : "low" === a ? 2e4 : isNaN(parseInt(a, 10)) ? 1e4 : a
  }, b.prototype.l = function(a, b) {
    for (var c in b) a.style[c] = b[c]
  }, b
});

// Initialisation

var canvasDiv = document.getElementById('particle-canvas');
var options = {
  particleColor: '#888',
  background: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/master/img/demo-bg.jpg',
  interactive: true,
  speed: 'medium',
  density: 'high'
};
var particleCanvas = new ParticleNetwork(canvasDiv, options);
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#particle-canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
h1 {
    text-align: center;
    position: inherit;
    float: none;
}
#container {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
#back,
.overstyle {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;


}
.overstyle h1{
    font-family: 'Open Sans Condensed', sans-serif;
    font-size: 230%;
    font-family: 'Indie Flower', cursive;
          width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
    
}
.overstyle {
    text-align: center;
    color: white;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
    <div id="particle-canvas" id="back"></div>
    <script src='https://rawgit.com/JulianLaval/canvas-particle-network/master/particle-network.min.js'></script>
    <script src="js/index.js"></script>
    <!--- Content Div --->
    <div style="width: 100%; color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.55);" class="overstyle">
      <h1>TestFont</h1>
    </div>
    <!--- End of Content Div --->
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried it on the example you provided - 
This worked for me:

```
.overstyle h1 {
  z-index:2;
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  left: 20px;
}
```